# IIS server redirect issue behind Cloudfront

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, amazon-cloudfront

I've got an asp.net website (let's say http://cdn.mysite.com) hosted on IIS and sat behind an Amazon CloudFront Distribution (using a CNAME to access the cdn.* url above, let's say the distribution URL is http://mysite.cloudfront.net).

If a user hits a folder/directory url without a trailing slash, the server will issue a redirect to the origin cdn url, so if a user navigates to http://mysite.cloudfront.net/thanks, they'll end up on http://cdn.mysite.com/thanks/ instead of http://mysite.cloudfront.net/thanks/

Any suggestions of how to fix this in asp.net / iis / cloudfront?

Comment: I'm assuming you've got some sort of URL rewriting in place - can you check your IIS config and feedback? You should be able to find it in your web.config - look for the <rewrite> section. You may have a specific rule named 'AddTrailingSlashRule' or similar.

Comment: Nothing in web.config - I thought this behaviour was by default in IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right - and rather than fighting it - have you configured CloudFront to whitelist host headers?

For each behaviour > Forward Headers > Select 'Whitelist' > Select 'Host' from the list and hit Add.

This setting ensures that the host header (mysite.cloudfront.net) is included in requests back to the origin (so make sure you've added mysite.cloudfront.net to your site bindings). I'd expect the redirect issued by IIS will use the correct domain name once this configuration is in place.

Comment: Spot on.

It even forwards through the CNAME I forward to Cloudfront's distribution DNS.

Problem solved!